# Laravel 5: DB Seed class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have this DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            Model::unguard();

            $this->call('MemberInvitationSeeder');
        }
    }
```

I have this file MemberInvitationSeeder.php, sibling to the DatabaseSeeder.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\MemberInvitation;

    class MemberInvitationSeeder extends Seeder {

        public function run()
        {
            MemberInvitation::truncate();

            MemberInvitation::create( [
                'id' => 'BlahBlah' ,//com_create_guid(),
                'partner_id' => 1,
                'fisrt_name' => 'Thats',
                'last_name' => 'Me',
                'email' => 'me@mymail.com',
                'mobile_phone' => '444-342-4234',
                'created_at' => new DateTime
            ] );

        }
    }
```

Now I call

```
php artisan db:seed
```

and I get:

```
[ReflectionException]                        
  Class MemberInvitationSeeder does not exist
```

I tried everything I could find including "composer dump-autoload". to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `$this->call('\MemberInvitationSeeder');` make any difference?

Comment: Or `use App\MemberInvitationSeeder` in `DatabaseSeeder.php`

Comment: It just claims \MemberInvitationSeeder isn't found...

Comment: use App\MemberInvitationSeeder has no effect. Still not found.

Comment: It's not registered as anything I believe. I just created it manually. Should it be "registered" somewhere?

Comment: @RM1970 No sorry, scratch that last comment. I don't think that was the issue. Will keep looking into it.

Comment: Did you remember to run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Yes. I run it. Still "Class doesn't exist"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I know the reason now.

The new class MemberInvitationSeeder wasn't in the autoloaded classes in the composer.json file.

It wasn't there because I added that class manually.

Now, going forward, if I add such classes again, what should I use in order for my class to automatically to the autoloader?

Comment: Take a look in your composer.json file.  In the `autoload` section, you should see where it's setting up the `classmap` and it should have `"database"` in the array which tells composer to add everything in that folder to the autoloader.  If it's not in there, that's your problem.  If it is in there, try `composer self-update` and then `composer dump` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 119):

**Step one** - generate seed:

```
php artisan make:seed MemberInvitationSeeder
```

**Step two** - In DatabaseSeeder.php add line:

```
$this->call(MemberInvitationSeeder::class);
```

**Step three**:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Step four**:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

This should work

---

If this isn't the clue, check the composer.json file and make sure you have code below in the "autoload" section:

```
"classmap": [
    "database"
],
```

Comment: running "composer dump-autoload " only thing i needed to do.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the current one is based on a false conclusion or missing knowledge.

Comment: Cool but a bit OT: You can use your model to seed database. Instead of `DB::table('my_foos')->insert(['col1' => 'Value 1'])` use `MyFoos::create(['col1' => 'Value1'])`. The benefit is, the auto-maintained `created_at` and `updated_at` are being filled out for you. While with `DB::table('x')->insert()` they are empty.

Answer (score 13):

I solved this by adding the class to the seeder file, with the instruction `use`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\YourClassName;
```

Answer (score 6):

This work for me

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan db:seed`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the similar error but I was using DB facade `DB::table` rather than model. I am posting the answer just in case somebody has similar issues.

The seeder file had namespace `namespace Database\Seeders;` and laravel was trying to look for DB class inside the namespace and hence the error appeared.

`Class 'Database\Seeders\DB' not found`.

**Resolutions:**

- Remove the namespace and run `composer dump-autoload`
- **OR** Add a backslash to  `\DB::table('stock_categories')->([ ... ]);` so Laravel starts looking the **DB facade** from root (*not from the namespace specified*)

Eg,

```php
\DB::table('MemberInvitation')->insert( [
         'id' => 'BlahBlah' ,//com_create_guid(),
         'partner_id' => 1,
         'fisrt_name' => 'Thats',
         'last_name' => 'Me',
         'email' => 'me@mymail.com',
         'mobile_phone' => '444-342-4234',
         'created_at' => new DateTime
    ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions doesn't work, try this one.
You may have changed the namespace (by default, it's "App").
What you need to do is to go to the `composer.json` file and check this:

```js
"autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          "database"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
      }
  },
```

If the namespace is App like this example, this solution is not for you.

Otherwise, take the namespace you found and insert that line into your seeder class:

```php
use NameSpaceFound\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include namespace if you want to use a string as a parameter

```
 $this->call('Database\Seeders\MemberInvitationSeeder');
```

Comment: There is no need to add path of the seeder file. `$this->call([MemberInvitationSeeder::class]);` only this is enough

Comment: Your way is enough, I agree, but mine works too. Just an althernative

Answer (score 0):

After making `php artisan make:seed SeederName`
then you need to run `composer dump-autoload` command after that
`php artisan db:seed` It is working for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem with laravel package with [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/package-skeleton-laravel)
to solve this problem just

1- append seeders path in composer.json of your package

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            ...
            "{packagename}\\{vendorname}\\Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders"
        }
    },
```

2. then go to your main project and update composer with `composer update`
3. auto-load your classess with `composer dump-autoload`

If it doesn't work delete **Vendor** folder and run `composer install`