# Target class [DataTypesTableSeederCustom] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using laravel6, and voyager, i'm creating artisan command for installation use cmd following `php artisan make: command EcommerceInstall`
, I recopy `DataTypesTableSeeder` from `database/seeder` and I rename it by `DataTypesTableSeederCustom`, I modify my file which I wrote `EcommerceInstall.php` but it gives me error `class [DataTypesTableSeederCustom] does not exist.`
i think i forget import the class but i don't know where .

**EcommerceInstall.php**

```
public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->confirm('this well delete all you current data and install the dummy default data, Are you sure ?')) {

                File::deleteDirectory(public_path('storage/products/dummy'));
                $this->callSilent('storage:link');
                $copySuccess = File::copyDirectory(public_path('img/products'),public_path('storage/products/dummy'));
                if($copySuccess){
                    $this->info('images succefully copied to storage folder');
                }
                $this->call('migrate:fresh', [
                    '--seed' => true,
                ]);
                $this->call('db:seed', [
                    '--class' => 'DataTypesTableSeederCustom'
                ]);

   $this->info('Dummy data installed');

        }
```

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` and try again

Comment: Also double-check the `namespace` directive in your custom class, and make sure it's using one from the namespaces defined for your project's autoloader (e.g. in the `"autoload"` element of your `composer.json` file).

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thx its work

Comment: You are welcome. I think is a possible duplicated question, so no need to write an answer [DB Seed class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176194/laravel-5-db-seed-class-not-found)